# Problem in solving a question related to sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series

**The question is** :

Prove that the equation $x^{n}+x^{n-1}+\dotsb +x-1 = 0$ has exactly one positive root for all $n \in N$ and if $\{b_n\}$ is the sequence of all positive roots of these equations, then prove that the sequence is convergent and it converges to $1/2$.

I proved that the first part by Descartes' rule of signs. It is hard for me to show the convergence of the sequence. It is even complicated for me to find the general term or $n$-th term of the sequence.

Comment: Multiply by $x-1$, and you may get something easier to work with.

Comment: Convergence should not be hard, the sequence of positive roots is decreasing and bounded below, That will help find the value.  By the way, existence and uniqueness of positive root can also be done by calculus.

Comment: Is it something that requires the concept of the method of bisection?

Comment: Apologies, I will not be able to help further today (sleep time); Bisection method is I think not relevant.

Comment: Have you thought of using Vieta's formulas? They might help.

Comment: Use MCT to show the sequence $\{a_n \}$ converges and also show $|a_n| < 1$.  You can take limits on $a_{n+1}^{n+1} - 1 = 2 (a_{n+1}-1)$ and get $2(a -1) =-1 \implies a = \frac 1 2$.

Comment: @Italian I thought about that but how to use it ? Here we are asked to consider only the positive roots that too unique ones. Vieta's formula uses all roots.

Comment: @Santosh you say $|a_n|<1$ using the mean value theorem right ? That if $f(x)=x^n+x^{n-1}+...+x-1$ then $f(0)=-1$ and $f(1)=n-1$ so, there must exist a $c$ between $ 0$ and $1 $ such that $f(c)=0$

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I was not aware of that, I will place a bounty next time I do the same.

Comment: @Chayan Thanks for your response.

Comment: if $a_n$ is root of $x + \dots x^n = 1$ then roots of $x + \dots x^{n  +1}= 1$ which is $a_{n+1}$ must be smaller than $a_n$ i.e. $a_{n+1} < a_{n} < a_2 < a_1 = 1$ With MCT, $\{ a_n \}$ is decreasing positive sequence thus converges. Let $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = a$ then you get your required result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that you know the unique positive root of $x^n+x^{n-1}+\cdots +x-1=0$ is between $0$ and $1$, which means $|b_n| < 1$ for all $n\ge 2$. By the definition of $b_n$,
$$
b_n^n + b_n^{n-1}+ \cdots + b_n =1
$$
and so
$$
b_{n+1}^{n+1}+ b_n^n + b_n^{n-1}+ \cdots + b_n > 1 = b_{n+1}^{n+1}+b_{n+1}^n +\cdots + b_{n+1}.
$$
Thus
\begin{align}
0 &< b_n^n - b_{n+1}^n + b_n^{n-1}-b_{n+1}^{n-1}+\cdots + b_n - b_{n+1}\\
&=(b_n-b_{n+1})(...)
\end{align}
so $b_n > b_{n+1}$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. $(b_n)$ is bounded and monotonously decreases, so $(b_n)$ converges by monotone convergence theorem. Let $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n = b$.
$$
b_n^n + b_n^{n-1}+ \cdots + b_n = \frac{b_n ( b_n^n -1)}{b_n-1}
$$
and so
$$
\frac{-b}{b-1}=1.
$$
Therefore $b=\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 4):

The equality is equivalent to
$$\frac{x - x^{n+1}}{1-x}=1$$
or
$$2 x -1 = x^{n+1}$$

Now, notice that $0<x< a_2 < 1$, so
$$0 < 2x-1< \frac{1}{a_2^{n+1}}$$
so
$$0 < x-\frac{1}{2} < \frac{1}{2 a_2^{n+1}}$$

Comment: How did you show $x<a_2 ?$

Comment: @Chayan: Ah, well the sequence $a_n$ is decreasing.